# TestNG: If a test throws exception, continue other tests

Tags: testng

In TestNG, if a test fails, I want to continue with other tests so that I can check what all tests failed.

How do I do it? If this can be done with some TestNG configuration, that would be better.

Comment: did I answer your question? Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your test fails because of an exception (or because of anything), unless you have a dependency, it will jump into the next test without problem.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you wanted to ask "If a validation fails within my test, I want it to continue with the rest of the test.".

If this is the case, what you want to use is **Soft Assertions**.
This object will collect all of your errors, and only fail and display them when you tell them.

```
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class ShoppingCartValidation {

@Test
public void testA() {
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    int a = 5;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    softAssert.assertTrue(b>a,"b should be greater than a.");

    try {
        c = a/b;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        softAssert.fail("There was an exception trying to divide " + a + " by " + b);
    }

    softAssert.assertEquals(c, 10, "b should be equals 10.");

    softAssert.assertAll(); // This line will make the test fail if any of the validations above failed, and will show all the failures.

}

}
```

**Error output:** 
[image: TestNG Soft Assert validation error output]

Hope this helps.